# Can global scoped variables be modified by other Cloud Function invocations?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Cloud Functions and have a question on the 'state' of global scope variables.

I know Cloud Functions are supposed to be stateless and global scoped variables are initialized for each instance (not invocation).

Would it be safe to assume that **for the duration of an invocation** a global variable would stay unchanged by other invocations? Consider the following snippet:

```
    var color = "blue" //global color variable

    async function logColor (req, res) => {
        var myColor = req.query.color
        color = myColor

        const checkColor = () => console.log(myColor === color)

        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var interval = setInterval(checkColor, 1000)

            setTimeout(() => {
                clearInterval(interval)
                resolve()
            }, 30000)
        })

        res.send()
    }
```

As you can see when the function is invoked, it reads a color query parameter and sets the global 'color' variable to that, then checks if the global variable is the same as the local one for 30 seconds.

I invoked it in a few different tabs using different colors and the output was always 'true', so I am assuming that it's safe to set global variables in a function invocation and expect them to be maintained for the duration of that invocation with no 'concurrency' from other invocations, as long as we are not using them to hold state between invocations.

Another example assuming `globalObj` will stay unchanged for the duration of an async operation

```
    var globalObj

    async function myFunc(req, res) {
        globalObj.id = uuid()
        globalObj.name = req.query.name

        res.send(await asyncOperation(globalObj))
    }
```

It this correct or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answer here by marian.vladoi is not entirely correct.

Global variables WILL be retained and reused between multiple invocations of the same function **on the same server instance**.  However, functions could be running on multiple server instances, so those global variables are not shared between the server instances.

It's perfect valid to use global variables as a way to cache or retain data for future invocations, but you don't want to use them to store application state, as there is no guarantee how long they will retain their values.

You might want to watch this video in a series that discusses how Cloud Functions works.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2mjfI0FYP7Y&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLm9A9rcHb1IkyQUu6QwbjdM&index=2&t=0s

Comment: But this means that for the duration of a single execution of a function I can expect any global variables to be 'locked' and not to be changed by anything but that function, correct?

Comment: It's only after the function is over that I can't rely on finding my data as I left it in the global variables when calling another function, if I understood correctly. During a single execution they're not going to change if not because of the current function execution

Comment: If you declare a global in your function's scope, then only the code running for that function can change the value.  It won't change unexpectedly.

Answer (score 1):

According to the oficial documentation each cloud function runs in its own isolated execution context.

Regarding auto-scaling and concurrency:

> Each instance of a function handles only one concurrent request at a
>   time. This means that while your code is processing one request, there
>   is no possibility of a second request being routed to the same
>   instance. Thus the original request can use the full amount of
>   resources (CPU and memory) that you requested.

You should not depend on Cloud Functions sharing variables or local memory.

You can find more information [Cloud Functions Execution Environment](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec)

Comment: This answer is not entirely correct.  Please see my answer here for more accurate details.

Comment: To improve it, change "Cloud Functions do not share variables or local memory" to "you should not depend on Cloud Functions sharing variables or local memory".